# Some hints to prove this axioms of probability equivalence?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space and $P:\mathcal A \to[0,\infty)$ that verifies:

$K1)$ $P(\Omega)=1$

$K2)$ Finite sum: If $A_1,A_2,...,A_n \in \mathcal A$ with $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset $ if $i\neq j$, then $P(\cup_{i=1}^nA_i)=\sum_{i=1}^nP(A_i)$

$K3)$ If $\{A_k\}_{k=1}^\infty\subset \mathcal A$ is a decreasing sequence with limit $\emptyset$, then $\{P(A_k)\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is also a decreasing sequence with limit $0$.

I don't know how to prove that those axioms imply these:

$I)$ $0\leq P(A)$ for all $A\in \mathcal A$

$II)$ Any collection of disjoint events $\{A_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ verifies $P(\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i)$

Comment: (I) is in the definition of $P$, namely, $P : \mathcal A\to [0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks! And if the codomain was $\Bbb R$, is it possible to prove the non negative property?

Comment: As I wrote already, (I) follows from the definition. There is nothing to show.

Comment: It was my answer below, but much shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $A:=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$, $B_n := \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$, and $C_n := A\setminus B_n$. Then $(C_n)$ is decreasing to the empty set, hence $P(C_n)\to 0$. Also $A = C_n\cup B_n$, where the union is disjoint. Thus,
$$
P(A) = P(C_n) + P(B_n) = P(C_n) + \sum_{i=1}^nP(A_i).
$$
Now, take the limit $n\to\infty$.